# Add input number/text to range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have string with input range

```
 <input form="send" type="range" min="40" max="300" name="width[]" value="40">
```

it means width of one part.
If user needs some parts he clicks add button and get new string with new input range.
So I get array with different values (size of parts).

Now I need to add input number/text which would repeat range value and vice versa. User can type a number and range input will be changed also. Or he changes input range and input number also get this value.

I know how to do it but without width array.
E.g.

```
 <input type="range" name="width" min="40" max="200" value="40"
 oninput="this.form.widthPlus.value=this.value" /> <input
 type="number" name="widthPlus" min="40" max="200" value="40"
 oninput="this.form.width.value=this.value" />
```

Can somebody tell how I can do that to input number reapeat value and also was cloned if user add new string with add button. 
I think I can do it with JS/jQuery only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just use a new `value` attribute everytime. Nothing like `width[]` (which does not work), but instead `width0`, `width1`, `width2`, ..

So somewhere in your code, you have a function which creates a new input element:

```
var counter = 0;
function addElement() {
    var html = '<input type="range"  name="width' +     counter + '" min="40" max="200" value="40" oninput="this.form.widthPlus' + counter + '.value=this.value" />' +
               '<input type="number" name="widthPlus' + counter + '" min="40" max="200" value="40" oninput="this.form.width'     + counter + '.value=this.value" />'; 
    $(".outerContainer").append(html);
    counter++;
}
```

And everytime the user clicks a button, you can call this function to add a new element.

There are also alternative ways that do not require the name-attribute to count upwards. You could just call a JS-function if the user enters something, and then use jQuery to determine which element was edited (n'th child). But this is a bit more complicated and requires more code.

Comment: thanks. I corrected some moment and both inputs is shown. But I have problems with values. I asked a new  question this topic

Answer (score 0):

This code is ok. I corrected it a little

```
    var counter = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var html = $("<input type='range'  name='width' + counter + '' min='40' max='200' value='40' oninput='this.form.widthPlus' + counter + '.value=this.value' />" + 
"<input type='number' name='widthPlus' + counter + '' min='40' max='200' value='40' oninput='this.form.width' + counter + '.value=this.value' />");
        $(".form-col-2").append(html);
        counter++;
    });
```