# Input range get value of input number and vice versa (oninput=...)

Tags: html, input

I have 2 inputs with type range and number which get values of each other.

Here is working code:

```
<form>
    <input type="range" name="height" min="0" max="20" value="0" oninput="this.form.heightPlus.value=this.value" />
    <input type="number" name="heightPlus" min="0" max="20" value="0" oninput="this.form.height.value=this.value" />
</form>
```

But I need to put into div, not in form.

How should I change oninput

```
oninput="this.form.width.value=this.value"
```

I tried smth like

```
$('input[name=height]').val()
```

but no result

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps you

```
<div>
    <input type='range' name="height" id='height' min='0' max='20' value='0' oninput='document.getElementById("heightPlus").value=this.value' />
    <input type='number' name="heightPlus" id='heightPlus' min='0' max='20' value='0' oninput='document.getElementById("height").value=this.value' />
</div>
```

For your fiddle change the Jquery code as below

**Html:**

```
<div class="gallery-slider" ></div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
var counter = 0;
$('.gallery-slider').append("<input type='range' id='width' name='width" + counter + "' min='40' max='200' value='40'/><input type='number' id='widthPlus' name='widthPlus" + counter + "' min='40' max='200' value='40'/>");
$(document).on('input', '#width', function(event) {
    $(this).next().val($(this).val());
});
$(document).on('input', '#widthPlus', function(event) {
    $(this).prev().val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: thanks. But I can't do this code working in my code. Can you help? http://jsfiddle.net/MikhailZ/2dJAN/1495/   I think that problem in quotation marks but I tried hundred versions and no result

Comment: thanks. Your code is great. But I have problem again. If you let I ask you. I had a question yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698929/add-input-number-text-to-range/45699269#45699269 about how add input number to range then get values to array. Final code: jsfiddle.net/MikhailZ/2dJAN/1496 but: 1. Counter always = 1 2. I changed .append to .html because had problem with cloning inputs when click submit, but now .html return min value of inputs that moment I click submit button. I broke my brain

Comment: what actual thing you need give more details about your scenario

Comment: I wrote more details this topic. Look please if you can. Thanks

Comment: no changes in this topic :/. give a fiddle with details in that

Comment: jsfiddle.net/MikhailZ/Lu22caa1 I added all code before submit button because it's big callback plugin. If you need more info let me know please. If you can't haelp write please also.

Answer (score 1):

In such a case, you would usually give each input element a unique `id` property and use `window.getElementById('idValue').value =...` to set the value. This does not even require jQuery.

HTML:

```
<input type="range" id="idValue" min="0" max="20" value="0" oninput="window.getElementById('otherIdValue')=this.value" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have "string" of 4 columns:
1. Select (type of thing)
2. Input range + (input number(now added)) (height of thing)
3. Input range + (input number(now added)) (width of thing)
4. Input readonly calculation

User enter data of first 3 columns get result then he can add one (then two,three...) more string (click add button) or go to callback form (submit button).
When he click submit form is opened and there are popup form whit some fields: name, phone, user datas in the textarea: 
1. Thing Type 1   40x60  2400
2. Thing Type 2   40x50  2000
....
Datas texarea gets via form="send".

Everything worked great but I need to add input number which duplicate input range value and vice versa.
Input range at first looked this way in html

```
<div class="gallery">
<input form="send" type="range" min="40" max="300" name="width[]" value="40">
</div>
```

then I deleted it from html and added via jQuery as you could see: jsfiddle.net/MikhailZ/2dJAN/1496

Now I have problems with counter. Name = width1 in every string.
Also problem with .append/.html
When I had .append when I got popup form I click submit button and got one more input range and input number in every div of every string.
I change to .html, no cloning but now when I get min input values to popup form. 
For example, user chose 1. Thing Type 1   100x60  6000
but in the form I get 1. Thing Type 1   40x40  6000

Comment: @PraveenKumar, https://jsfiddle.net/MikhailZ/Lu22caa1/ I added all code before submit button because it's big callback plugin. If you need more info let me know please